# How to Download Files based on a pattern in Python when using FTP_TLS

Tags: python, ftp

I'm actually trying to do FTP and get all the files with a specific File pattern using python.
I was able to do FTP and download a single file form ftp server as below but, can suggest me how do I download all files on that ftp server based on file pattern 'sample_'.

```
ftps.login(user='abc@xyz.com', passwd = 'PassWord')
'230 User logged in, proceed.'

>>> ftps.retrlines('LIST') # List Directories
drwx------   1 owner group            0 Apr 29 11:27 Get Started
drwx------   1 owner group            0 Jul  7 02:29 Folder_1
'226 Closing data connection.'

>>> ftps.cwd('Folder_1')  # Change Directory
'250 Directory changed to /Folder_1'

>>> ftps.retrlines('LIST') # List items in the directory
drwx------   1 owner group            0 Jul  7 02:29 .
drwx------   1 owner group            0 Jan 30  1970 ..
-rw-------   1 owner group          491 Jul  2 14:04 smaple_test1.csv
-rw-------   1 owner group          365 Jul  7 02:22 smaple_test2.csv
-rw-------   1 owner group         9948 Jun 30 14:34 smaple_test3.csv
-rw-------   1 owner group         9948 Jun 30 14:34 note1.csv
-rw-------   1 owner group         9948 Jun 30 14:34 note2.csv
'226 Closing data connection.'


>>> ftps.retrbinary('RETR smaple_test1.csv', gFile.write) # Download a single file
'226 Transfer complete.'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ftps = FTP_TLS(host)
ftps.login(user = "ftp.url.com", passwd ="password")

ftps.cwd('sdir')  # Change Directory on FTP Server 

files = ftps.nlst(sfrmt)
for f in files:
    with open(f, 'wb') as fh:
        ftps.retrbinary('RETR ' + f, fh.write)
```